# how to add nodes on a root pane from a different class?

Tags: javafx, root, pane

I'm trying to add a node on my root pane. If i try to call a method outside the class, nodes are not displayed on the root pane. However if i call the method within the class, it works.

```
public class MainLayout extends AnchorPane{

@FXML public Pane root_pane;

public MainLayout(){
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/MainLayout.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try{
        fxmlLoader.load();
    }catch(IOException exception){
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}

@FXML
private void initialize(){
    ShapeEllipse ellipse = new ShapeEllipse();
    ellipse.setText("Main");

    Arrows arrow = new Arrows();
    arrow.relocate(10,20);
    root_pane.getChildren().addAll(ellipse,arrow);

}
public void insertShape(){


        ShapeInputOutput inputOutput = new ShapeInputOutput();
        inputOutput.relocate(10,50);
        root_pane.getChildren().add(inputOutput);
}
```

Here's my 2nd controller class

```
public class AddShapes  extends AnchorPane{

MainLayout main = new MainLayout();
ShapeInputOutput inputOutput1 = new ShapeInputOutput();

public AddShapes(){
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(); 
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/resources/AddShapes.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try{
        fxmlLoader.load();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    addActions();
}

public void addActions(){

    inputOutput1.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            main.insertShape();

}
```

Comment: In `AddShapes`, you create a new `MainLayout` instance, but you never seem to display it in the UI anywhere (unless I am missing something). So when you call `insertShape()` on that instance, it presumably modifies it, but since it's never displayed you won't see anything.

Comment: how can i display UI on my root pane sir? Cause usually, what i do is just simply add the node on the root pane. I tried to check the size every time the action is being performed, It shows that the size increases however the nodes are not displayed.

Comment: You're missing my point. Presumably somewhere else in your code you have another instance of `MainLayout` that is displayed somewhere. You need to call `insertShape()` on *that* instance, not the new instance you create. If that doesn't make sense, you probably need to create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.